# Facebook Posts are revealed after refreshing the page: Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

After struggling, I finally came across the solution for what I was trying to achieve. I have successfully integrated the posts of Facebook with my application.

But there is only one issue. I want to have the post in the textarea after the person logins. But I could not see the post unless I refresh the page of the website.

Here is the code that I am trying to perform:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
function getUserData() {
    FB.api('/me', {fields: 'email, posts'}, function(response) {
        document.getElementById('for_analysis').innerHTML = 'Hello ' + response.posts.data[0].message;

    });
}

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    //SDK loaded, initialize it
    FB.init({
        appId      : 'MyID',
        xfbml      : true,
        version    : 'v2.10'
    });

    //check user session and refresh it
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            //user is authorized
            //document.getElementById('loginBtn').style.display = 'none';
            getUserData();

        } else {
            //user is not authorized
            document.getElementById('for_analysis').innerHTML = '';
        }
    });
};


//load the JavaScript SDK
(function(d, s, id){
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.com/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

//add event listener to login button
document.getElementById('loginBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    //do the login
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            //user just authorized your app
            //document.getElementById('loginBtn').style.display = 'none';
            getUserData();
            //document.location.reload(true)
        }
    }, {scope: 'email,user_posts', return_scopes: true});
}, false);

</script>
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="2" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="true" data-use-continue-as="true" data-scope = "email,user_posts"></div>
```

Kindly, let me know what I need to do to make the content visible after a person logs in.

I tried to reload the page after the `getUserData()` is executed using the command `window.location.reload()`, also tried : `window.location.reload(true)`, 
`document.location.reload()`, and `document.location.reload(true)`.

but the page didn't stopped refreshing, hence, neglected the reloading part.

Please suggest a better solution if any.

Comment: If you replace `getUserData();` (inside the click event handler) with `location.reload();` as you say, it shouldn't keep reloading the page.

Comment: @Archer Sorry but I didn't got your point. Please can you help me?

Comment: auto-reloading the page with javascript is not necessary...

Comment: ..and PLEASE don´t reload the page with javascript in a function that is called on page load...of course that´s an endless loop.

Answer (score -1):

You are using `FB.login` AND the login button. Use your own button and call `FB.login` on your own. Right now you aren´t even using `FB.login`, only the login button without any callback after successful login.

Alternatively, you can use the `onlogin` callback of the login button and forget about `FB.login`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web/login-button/#settings

Comment: downvote? why? my answer is 100% correct...please explain if something is missing.

Comment: I tried the javascript from your website: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/ .... I thought it will work but as you can see in my question. I tried to modify t too.

Comment: you are not using the js from my website, i am not using the official login button there ;) please read my answer, it´s definitely the issue and 100% correct.

Comment: i mean... "document.getElementById('loginBtn')" ... you don´t even have a button with the id "loginBtn"...just create a div or button with that id and remove the current one (with the class "fb-login-button").

Comment: ok I tried remove the listener part and replaced it with a login function which I called `onlogin` event. But now after logout, I am getting the login dialog box. I don't understand what is the issue.

Comment: You might be 100% correct, but I have not downvoted you. Someone else might have.

Comment: after logout? of course you get the login dialog box if you are logged out...you need to be logged in on facebook, but the js sdk handles that for you.